# Rails: how to redirect to "show" action of nested resource in a "create" action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I currently have 3 models: user, album, photo. I've made registration, but not login/sessions yet, since I am trying to have the album/photo creation finished first. However, when I create an album the URL changes from

`http://localhost:3000/users/13/albums/new` (no problem)

to

`http://localhost:3000/albums/76/photos/76` (problem)

the issues here are: 
1. the user_id disappears from the url.
2. it's sending me to the wrong url. As you can see below, I am redirecting to [@user, @album]. Isn't that supposed to be the show action of the albums controller? I wanted something like /users/13/albums/1 as the url. Instead, it's sending me to `photos#show`.
3. even though it's the wrong link, why are the album id and the photo id are always the same? 76/76 77/77 etc... I don't know where that is coming from..

here are my files:

album controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
  @photo = @album.photos.build(params[:photo])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @album.save
      format.html { redirect_to album_photo_path(@album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
end

def edit
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to [@user, @album], notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end 
end
```

albums/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for (@album), url: user_albums_path, :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>



<div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>


    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

    <br>

    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

config/routes

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :albums 
end

resources :albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

let me know if you need anymore files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the series of requests that your use case runs through:

First, the form submits some data to your `Album#create` action.

After the `Album#create` request succeeds, the request is redirected to the `Albums#show` action.

In the `Albums#show` action, the controller instantiates `@user` and `@album` with your current User and the new Album, then builds a new Photo object within the Album's `photos` collection.

The action *then* saves the `Album` record again. Since nothing has changed, this doesn't actually do anything. But it does do nothing *successfully*, so it proceeds to redirect the request to `album_photo_path`, and **this is where things go pear-shaped**. This route, as defined, leads to a `Photo#show` action, in the context of the photo's parent Album. The route expects *two* arguments, an Album and a Photo. As invoked in your code, it *shouldn't work*—throwing a Routing Error exception instead. (Believe me, I tried.)

Instead of getting hung up on minutae like that, though, I'm going to make a blind recommendation instead!

It sounds like you didn't intend for your `Album#show` action to save the album and redirect to `Photo#show` via a malformed route. I think this is the source of all three of your issues. And, ultimately, I think your `AlbumsController`'s `show` action needs to look like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
end
```

Hope this helps!

---

#### Edited to address Edmund's comment:

Absolutely, you can set up the `Album#show` action to allow users to add photos. This would involve two changes to what I suggest above.

In your controller, you would instantiate a new Photo on `@album`'s Photos collection, much as you had earlier:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
  @photo = @album.photos.build
end
```

Then, in the `Album#show` template (e.g. `app/views/albums/show.html.erb`), you'd include a form for submitting a new photo:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @album, @photo] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :caption %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
<%- end %>
```

This form would submit its contents to the `user_album_photos_path`, which you may note does not yet exist. So the final change would be to nest Photos as a resource in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

This will provide you with the route needed to use the form. Now you'll just need to add a `Photo#create` action to handle the form submission, and you're off to the races!

Comment: I actually wanted to put a form with "photo#new" functioning in the show action of the album (so people could see what the pics in the album and upload new ones from one page). Is this not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your create action should look like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_album_path(@album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: when I change the redirect to what you mentioned, it gives me an error on form submission Routing Error

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"albums", :user_id=>#<Album id: 83, name: "fsdafdssadf", created_at: "2012-10-03 02:32:18", updated_at: "2012-10-03 02:32:18", description: "fsdaads">}`

Comment: @bigpotato I needed to change it to `user_album_path(album: @album, user: current_user)` this also worked  `user_album_path(album_id: @album.id, user: current_user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

If your nested routes are like below

```
 resources :albums do
   resources :photos
 end
```

Then you can redirect to show action from creating a successful object like below:

```
album_photos_path(@album, @photo)
```